# Gmail Ajax interface

Tags: jquery, ajax, gmail

I would like to create something similar to Gmails interface. Especially the way contacts are managed is very interesting.

I'm not a Javascript guru, but know my way around jQuery.

Thanks!

Comment: What exxactly you want? their contact interface, inbox  which one?

Comment: What's your question? Anyway you must understand that a lot of efforts and time has been put into the present day gmail by a team of experienced engineers. So yeah you can make a simple app but you should not compare it with gmail.

Comment: @Shoban. I'm talking about the whole way their interface works. Adding contacts without refresh. Adding pictures to the contacts without refresh. Searching etc... So mainly the way their contact manager works.

Comment: well it is not a simple thing to expain the whoel here. What have you done so far? May be we can split out the module and descuss.

Comment: Shoban. I haven't done anything yet. I was just looking for some tips.

Comment: You need to give a bit more detail.  Edit your question and provide exactly what you want to create.

Answer (score 7):

Tip: start with something simpler.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) for advanced projects like this one, if you're familiar with Java.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not familiar with Java. I use PHP.

Comment: Get familiar then. This is really the only way to produce something with that Google look & feel.

Comment: @henk, I'm also a PHP programmer like you and I learnt Java in about 1 week. The syntax of Java and PHP are very similar, and likely you'll find it very easy to learn too. I followed this tutorial: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/

Comment: @ Seanyboy. Why do I need Java for this? As far as i know Google uses Python.

Comment: @Henk Python is for server-side programming, for client programming Google builds their projects in java, and then uses their google web toolkit package to translate the java to javascript. This gives them the strenght of java, object oriented programming, and better debugging options, as well as handle cross browser support easily

Comment: It seems that they use **JavaScript**, not Java. When Java tries to run in my browser a pop up pops up about Java. So, I'm almost 100% sure it is JavaScript...

Answer (score 2):

Ajax (when done right) will require at least advanced knowledge of AJAX. Sure you can use JQuery for somethings, while you're at it, you can also use some Microsoft Ajax components, but in the end, if you want your app to run well, you're eventually going to have to get under the hood, and iron out kinks or build some JS components yourself.

I suggest you spend 2-3 weeks first getting up to speed with how Ajax works (remember you're going to have to optimize for all the browsers you want to support).

Even after you've mastered the basics, you're still going to have to learn about browser memory leaks and closures (lambda functions).

I don't mean to put you off building your site, but I don't think you can slap a quality result together in minutes using JQuery alone, its just not that simple.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into something like the [sproutcore](http://www.sproutcore.com/) framework.

Essentially its a good framework for rich-client web applications, like that of gmail.

[Otherinbox](http://www.otherinbox.com/) useses to accomplish the same ends.

Answer (score 0):

the concept is fairly easy if you know JQuery or any other AJAX framework already.  Simply customize/utilize existing jquery widgets, caching&paging,making ajax calls, etc.